# java program not getting inside while loop for unique row result set

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle9i

I have a result set that should contain 1 row (I have tested this). My program is not getting inside the `while(rs2.next())` loop, I have noticed this after debugging. that's why I'm getting SQLException : not all variables bound.

```
ResultSet constitues = cnx.createStatement().executeQuery(Request.getConstitues());

            while(constitues.next()){
                PreparedStatement ps = cnx.prepareStatement(Request.setNewConstitue());
                PreparedStatement ps2 = cnx.prepareStatement(Request.getDossierFromNumeroParcelle());

                ps2.setInt(1, constitues.getInt("NUM_ORDRE"));
                ps2.setInt(2, constitues.getInt("NUM_PARCELLE"));

                        //rs2 contains one row
                ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                        // Program is not entering this loop
                while(rs2.next()){
                   ps.setInt(1, rs2.getInt("NUM_DOSSIER"));
                   ps.setString(2, rs2.getString("INDICE"));
                   ps.setString(3, constitues.getString("OBSERVATIONS"));
                   ps.setInt(4, constitues.getInt("TYPE_CONSISTANCE"));
                }

                ps.executeUpdate();
                rs2.close();
                ps.close();

            }
```

`Request.getConstitues()` is :

```
 select * from PARC_CONSTITUES
```

`Request.setNewConstitue()`  is :

```
Insert into CONSTITUE(NUM_DOSSIER,INDICE,Observation,CODE_CONSISTANCE) values(?,?,?,?)
```

`Request.getDossierFromNumeroParcelle()` is :

```
select NUM_DOSSIER,INDICE from PARC_PARCELLES where num_ordre = ? and num_parcelle= ?
```

Why program is not getting inside the while loop ?

Comment: What is the ps2 SQL? Have you tested the SQL to make sure it returns rows?

Comment: Yes I have tested it the dbms side, it returns always 1 row.

Comment: If rs2 returns more than one row, the execute update needs to be in the while loop.

Comment: no, it returns always exactly one record

Comment: It would be beneficial if you posted the SQL statements that you are preparing.

Comment: Is all the existing data committed in the database? Only having one row suggests maybe you just added it, and can query it fine in the same session, but no other session can see it yet. Maybe. Have you debugged the values you're actually getting back and using from the `constitues.getInt()` calls, and that they are exactly what you use when running the query directly in the DB? (Vague feeling named parameters can be an issue).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i suspect data is not available in DB or its failing to retrieve from DB.

but any way check this condition before you go for while loop

```
boolean isEmpty = ! rs.first();
```

and print `isEmpty` for debugging.

so use something like this

```
if(!isEmpty)
{
 while(rs2.next()){
                   ps.setInt(1, rs2.getInt("NUM_DOSSIER"));
                   ps.setString(2, rs2.getString("INDICE"));
                   ps.setString(3, constitues.getString("OBSERVATIONS"));
                   ps.setInt(4, constitues.getInt("TYPE_CONSISTANCE"));
}
            }
```

Comment: actually the prepared statement was not returning any results, it's really a pitty that oracle jdbc driver can not log sql final requests after binding parameters, I'm trying to install Log4JDBC to work as a proxy driver, intercepting sql requests and displaying them.

Comment: ya ..sometime passing query as a string to ps2.executeQuery(); method like ps2.executeQuery(sql); where sql="some prapared statement"..then this works and gets result sometimes..

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you move  ps.executeUpdate() into the  while(rs2.next())  loop your code will work as you are expecting. As it is now, whether you get results or not, it will call the executeUpdate. If the rs2.next() != true then you will get the error you are experiencing.